# How many spanning trees does the cycle graph C2014 have?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How many spanning trees does the cycle graph $C_{2014}$ have?

How do I create a bipartite graph and use it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  How many edges does a spanning tree on $2014$ vertices have?  How many edges are in $C_{2014}$? I don't know what a bipartite graph has to do with this.